# Point Kernel for Jupyter Notebook at Matlab

Tags: matlab, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get Jupyter Notebook to work with Matlab. I found a very helpful [blog post](https://anneurai.net/2015/11/12/matlab-based-ipython-notebooks) about this which got me as far as being able to create a MATLAB notebook. The blog post proposes the following steps:

1. Download and install Anaconda.
2. Install the Python packages `pymatbridge` and `matlab_kernel`.
3. Define the path to the MATLAB executable by typing the following in a terminal:

   ```
   echo "export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE=/Applications/MATLAB_2015b.app/bin/matlab" >> ~/.bash_profile.
   ```
4. Restart terminal. Then using MATLAB from a Jupyter Notebook should work.

My issue is with the third step, which is to point the kernel to the MATLAB executable. It is written for someone using a Mac, and I am on Windows 10. I'm not familiar enough with what is being done here to "translate" this step for Windows. Here are the instructions for a Mac:

I would deeply appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this step in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the command

```
 echo "export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE=/Applications/MATLAB_2015b.app/bin/matlab" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

in the terminal appends the text

```
export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE=/Applications/MATLAB_2015b.app/bin/matlab
```

to the file `~/.bash_profile`. This file is loaded every time you open a terminal on OS X. The `export` command is used to create an environment variable. So with this command, the environment variable `MATLAB_EXECUTABLE` is created and has the value `/Applications/MATLAB_2015b.app/bin/matlab`.

This environment variable is needed by the `matlab_kernel` module, as described in its [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matlab_kernel).

To set an environment variable on Windows (7+), you can use the `setx` command, as described in [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt). Thus, instead of the `echo ...` line, you should call

```
setx MATLAB_EXECUTABLE "C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\matlab.exe"
```

Note that you'll need admin rights for that.

Comment: This worked, thank you for helping and providing some links so I could understand what is being done.

Comment: My matlab is 2018a version, I typed 'echo "export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE=/Applications/MATLAB_2018a.app/bin/matlab" ' in the conda prompt, then I typed 'export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE=/Applications/MATLAB_2018a.app/bin/matlab', it says 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.