# Matlab error when displaying plots

Tags: matlab, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get Matlab to display a plot, and I keep getting the following error:

File , line 0, in @(h,i)print(h,sprintf('C:\Users\L_Iguana\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp58ui8ock/%i',i),'-dpng','-r96')
Cannot create output file 'C:.png'.

Has anyone ever seen an error like this, and could you suggest what might have gone wrong? I am not sure where to start troubleshooting. Since this was working in the past, I think I may have moved or updated something, but I can't figure out what.

For context, where I am trying to get the plot to show up is inside a Jupyter Notebook running Matlab, the steps I went through to do that are here:

[Point Kernel for Jupyter Notebook at Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214871/point-kernel-for-jupyter-notebook-at-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the single backslash (it's an escape character). Either change the `sprintf` to double up the backslashes and change the slash next to the `%i`, as follows:

```
sprintf('C:\\Users\\L_Iguana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\tmp58ui8ock\\%i',i)
```

or you can reverse the slashes, instead:

```
sprintf('C:/Users/L_Iguana/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp58ui8ock/%i',i)
```